# Patch class library / dll's using WiX 3.0

Tags: c#, wix, wix3

Is it possible to patch dll's using WiX 3.0 ?

I am trying to create a WiX 3.0 patch for a .net 3.5 project. 
The patch has all the static file changes (aspx, config file etc) but the changes made to code behind (dll) is not getting picked up in the patch.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the WiX toolset supports patching all files. Is it possible that there were no changes to the file? If that is the case, the WiX toolset is smart enough to skip the file since there is no reason to patch it if it didn't change.